# OracleDataAdapter accessing return values from a batch insert

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I'm using the Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataAdapter to batch insert rows into our system, the BatchSize is 250. We need to do something with a returned value from the batch insert for each insert that's taken place. The adapter is created like so:

```
OracleDataAdapter adapter = MakeMyAdapter(cn, table.TableName);
adapter.UpdateBatchSize = 250;
adapter.RowUpdated += new OracleRowUpdatedEventHandler(adapter_Table_RowUpdated);
adapter.Update(table);
```

where `table` is a `DataTable` with rows we want to insert (named correctly to the oracle table we want to insert into)
`cn` is an `IDbConnection` of an established oracle connection.

in `MakeMyAdapter` the `adapter.InsertCommand` is set to a new `OracleCommand`, table mappings are setup, etc. The insert is dynamically generated depending on what table we're inserting into. but in its essence it's

```
insert into myFirstTable (myPK, col1, col2) VALUES (mySequence.nextVal, :val1, :val2) returning myPK into :myReturnValue;
```

The adapter_Table_RowUpdated handler is called, we get an OracleRowUpdatedEventArgs (lets call it "e" ;)).
`e.Command` appears to be the last run command. If i inspect the command, it has 1 set of parameters which is consistent with the last row in the supplied `DataTable` but the `myReturnValues` parameter on the command is empty and I cannot see a way of getting all the different `myReturnValue`s out of the event. I've looked at doing `e.CopyToRows` but this looks to be the input rows from the DataTable, not the result of the command (Which makes sense)

my question is: Is this a supported solution using `OracleDataAdapter`s? Should I be able to get all the rows individual return values out of the `OracleRowUpdatedEventArgs` and if so, how?